# TransitionFromView crashes - iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, transition

In my app I have a list of items in a table view. Tapping on one of them, the app shows details of the item. Details appear and by back button of navigation controller, the app returns to list.

In the detail view I have implemented a method to swipe gesture in order to change the view to the details of the second element of the list and so on. To do thant I use "transitionFromView" inside a oneFingerSwipeLeft method. The aidea is to reuse the same view where only inside info change.

The method that changes view by is:

```
- (void)oneFingerSwipeLeft:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    int idx=currentIdx;
    if (idx ==[todasLasTapas count]-1) {   //last object vuelvo al primero
        idx= -1;
    }
    ClassInfo *info =[allInfo objectAtIndex:idx+1];
    //VIEW CONTROLLER
    MoreInfo *moreInfoController =[[MoreInfo alloc]initWithNibName:@"MoreInfoController" bundle:nil];

    //passing the details to view
    moreInfoController.id = info.uniqueId;
    moreInfoController.name = info.name;
    [UIView transitionFromView:self.view
                       toView:moreInfoController.view
                       duration:1
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve 
                       completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             [self.view removeFromSuperview];
                    }];
}
```

It works, but only on the first swipe finger. On the second swipe app crashes, showing only (lldb) output msg.

The crash happens when I try to charge the "third" view by the finger swipe. But, trying to debug using NSLOG, code doesn't entry again in the method

```
-(void)oneFingerSwipeLeft:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
```

the lldb bt response is:

```
(lldb) bt
* thread #1: tid = 0x1f03, 0x0187b09b libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 15, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x8)
    frame #0: 0x0187b09b libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 15
    frame #1: 0x00a7885a UIKit`_UIGestureRecognizerSendActions + 139
    frame #2: 0x00a7799b UIKit`-[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:] + 333
    frame #3: 0x00a790df UIKit`-[UIGestureRecognizer _delayedUpdateGesture] + 46
    frame #4: 0x00a7bd2d UIKit`___UIGestureRecognizerUpdate_block_invoke_0543 + 57
    frame #5: 0x00a7bcac UIKit`_UIGestureRecognizerRemoveObjectsFromArrayAndApplyBlocks + 331
    frame #6: 0x00a73a28 UIKit`_UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 1348
    frame #7: 0x007e0972 UIKit`-[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 1283
    frame #8: 0x007e0e53 UIKit`-[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 98
    frame #9: 0x007bed4a UIKit`-[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 436
    frame #10: 0x007b0698 UIKit`_UIApplicationHandleEvent + 9874
    frame #11: 0x026eadf9 GraphicsServices`_PurpleEventCallback + 339
    frame #12: 0x026eaad0 GraphicsServices`PurpleEventCallback + 46
    frame #13: 0x019b9bf5 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
    frame #14: 0x019b9962 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 146
    frame #15: 0x019eabb6 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 2118
    frame #16: 0x019e9f44 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 276
    frame #17: 0x019e9e1b CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    frame #18: 0x026e97e3 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 88
    frame #19: 0x026e9668 GraphicsServices`GSEventRun + 104
    frame #20: 0x007adffc UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1211
    frame #21: 0x000184fd pruebasTapas`main(argc=1, argv=0xbffff2e0) + 141 at main.m:16
(lldb)
```

Anyone could help me, please?

Comment: please provide a stacktrace

Comment: I just update my answer

Answer (score 0):

try something simple

```
-(void) viewDidLoad
{
   UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swiped)];
   swipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
   //rest of the code
}


-(void) swiped
{
    [self viewWillAppear:YES];
}
```

Reload the view using the data in your viewWillAppear

Comment: Tx for answer. What do you refear on reload the view?